# PC starts, but no display from the monitor

Tags: display, motherboard, desktop-computer

so I am building my first PC, i watched videos and bought the pieces with my brother who has build PCs before. Everything is compatible, but when I start the PC it doesn't show anything on the monitor. I have been troubleshooting for a while and I can't seem to find a solution.

The motherboard has led lights that indicate when something is wrong(CPU, DRAM, VGA, BOOT) but these flash for a second when it is booted and then they turn off, but the system keeps running.

Pc Specs:

CPU Ryzen 3 3100

Mobo Asrock 550 Phantom Gaming 4

Ram Gskill aegis 2x8gb 3200mhz

Psu 600W 80+ bronze

GPU Asus RX 580 (If i am correct the mobo has integrated graphics but neither of them work when i boot my PC)

M.2 nvme ssd (Only storage device)

Answer (score 0):

Your SSD doesn’t come with windows or any other OS installed so it would be normal to have no hdmi output on your screen after boot.

Have you tried spamming delete or f2 on boot, you should enter the BIOS/UEFI for your motherboard, where you will see any output.

Although you should be seeing the boot screen for your motherboard on startup, which is odd.

If that doesn’t work I would try looking at the connections of your CPU and GPU.

Comment: Yes i have tried pressing f2 and delete to enter bios, but it doesnt even post anything, idk. I removed and inserted both the gpu and cpu but it starts, fans start working and gpu gets warm but still no signal on monitor, i double checked my hdmi cable. I have a windows iso file on usb to install it, but it doesnt even post anything.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/206319/Monitor+no+signal+after+start+up it could be not enough power. Also if you have a buzzer, plug it into the motherboard and it should beep to show you and error messages, and you will be able to look it up.

Comment: You might not have enough power to the pc seeing as your motherboard lights only flash, but I’m not sure because I’ve never had that issue before